# CKFinder when inserting images via drag and drop (Incorrect server response)

Tags: coldfusion, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm trying to use CKFinder 2.6.3 from this site (https://ckeditor.com/ckfinder/download/) with CKEditor and I'm getting an error when using drag and drop. It says "Incorrect server response." I can use the Browse Server and the upload functions but the drag and drop is the only thing giving the error.

I am using the example that was provided in the CKFinder download:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
        if ( typeof CKEDITOR !== 'undefined' ) {
            CKEDITOR.addCss( 'img {max-width:100%; height: auto;}' );
            var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                extraPlugins: 'uploadimage,image2',
                removePlugins: 'image',
                height:350
            } );

            CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '../' ) ;

        } else {
            document.getElementById( 'description' ).innerHTML = '<div class="tip-a tip-a-alert">This sample requires working Internet connection to load CKEditor from CDN.</div>'
        }
    </script>
```

In the console, it says:

```
ckeditor.js:19 [CKEDITOR] Error code: filetools-response-error. 
{responseText: "//{"uploaded":1,"error":{"message":"A file with th…ncements\/images\/2367_093051_750_589115(1).jpg"}"}
responseText: "//{"uploaded":1,"error":{"message":"A file with the same name is already available. The uploaded file was renamed to \"2367_093051_750_589115(1).jpg\".","number":201},"fileName":"2367_093051_750_589115(1).jpg","url":"\/pictures\/Announcements\/images\/2367_093051_750_589115(1).jpg"}"
__proto__: Object
```

I have read in some posts that you have to specify responseType=json but I'm not sure where to put that.

Comment: How are you providing the path to upload file to?

Comment: In the "config.cfm" file, I am setting the config.baseURL and config.baseDir values to the folder for the files to go to. 
config.baseUrl = "/pictures/Announcements/";
config.baseDir = 'C:/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/wwwroot/websitedir/pictures/Announcements/';

Comment: Also, can you add the code which captures this file and tries to upload in the coldfusion side?

Comment: I think that code is buried down in the CKFinder files. The only thing I'm aware of is the config.cfm file where you define your base directory and base URL and CKFinder takes care of everything else.

Comment: So, a normal upload is working but not drag and drop, right? Looking at the upload response `responseText` I think in Coldfusion Administrator `secureJSONPrefix`(`Prefix serialized JSON with`) seems to be set as `//`. Is that correct?

Comment: RRK...you are correct. I had this option "Unchecked" on the test server but on the live server it was checked. Unchecking this option resolved my issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might be having this issue. RRK pointed out that there is an option in the Coldfusion Administrator for "Prefix serialized JSON with //". I unchecked this option and it resolved the issue for me.